# Request Response Differs from Device | PHP, Windows Server, React, MySQL

Tags: php, windows, hosting, windows-server-2022, fastroute

**Details :**

- Frontend : React
- API : PHP, FastRoute Library (Don't Judge, But I'm using xampp)
- Database : MySQL ~ Remotely Hosted

The task was to build an application and host it on a network. The system is meant to be only accessible to the local network. Therefore I settled on a simple Domain Controller with DHCP. Everything seems to be working fine. I have set up the DC with DHCP and also configured the inbound rules. The entire application is now accessible via the clients and for the most part works fine.

**Local Environment Details :**

- Windows 10
- Remote MySQL Database -> Same as Server
- Locally Ran Vite App
- Locally Ran XAMPP

**Domain Controller Server Details :**

- Windows Server 2022
- Remote MySQL Database
- `npm run dev -- --host` to host on the network
- XAMPP Configured to host on the network
- Inbound rules on port : `5173` and `80`

**AD User/Client Details :**

*Yes, the client can access the webapp. It can almost do everything I can Locally aside from a few things like the given problem*

- Windows 10
- Tried With Chrome
- Tried With Edge

**The issue :**

Local Environment :
JSON Data that gets stored in localStorage stay the correct datatype. For example if I say `{currPage : 5}` then it stays like that.

Server + Client :
JSON Data that gets stored in localStorage all becomes string datatype. For example if I say `{currPage : 5}` then it turns into `{currPage : 5}`.

I thought that it would be a browser issue, but trying it locally with the same browser as the Client works just fine. DataType doesn't change. Not a big issue since `parseInt()` fixes it.

Though here comes the important part. A Request like fetching images returns an array with objects when it's done `locally`. Once I try requesting it from the `Client`, it returns 0 results. I double checked the payload and it's the exact same data which is to be expected, but the response isn't. I personally am super confused and I have no clue where to begin. Unfortunately the server isn't allowed to stay on since it's at school so I can't test it right now. I'm currently just looking for possible ideas as to what is going wrong.

The Method For Fetching The Images Is this :

```php
 try {
            $base_query = "SELECT * FROM afbeelding WHERE record_id = :record_id && tabelnaam = :tabelnaam";

            $qry = $this->CONN->prepare($base_query);
            $qry->bindParam(":record_id", $record_id);
            $qry->bindParam(":tabelnaam", $tabelnaam);
            $qry->execute();




            if (!$qry->rowCount()) {
                http_response_code(404);
                print_r(json_encode(["message" => "No Results Found"]));
                return;
            }

            $response = $qry->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


            print_r(json_encode($response));

        } catch (PDOException $err) {
            print_r(json_encode(["message" => $err]));
            http_response_code(500);
        }

    }
```

**The Payload Looks Like This :**

```
tabelnaam: product
record_id: 1
```

**Locally The Response Returns :**

```js
[
  {
    "id": 12,
    "img_url": "image0-1708893712681.png",
    "record_id": 1,
    "tabelnaam": "product"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "img_url": "image1-1708893712685.png",
    "record_id": 1,
    "tabelnaam": "product"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "img_url": "image2-1708893712686.png",
    "record_id": 1,
    "tabelnaam": "product"
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "img_url": "image3-1708893712698.png",
    "record_id": 1,
    "tabelnaam": "product"
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "img_url": "image0-1709673514264.png",
    "record_id": 1,
    "tabelnaam": "product"
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "img_url": "image0-1709673523113.png",
    "record_id": 1,
    "tabelnaam": "product"
  }
]
```

If I make this same request from the client, I get `'No Results Found'` since that is what it's supposed to return **if there is no data**